# Why is the text on some questions larger than other questions?

Tags: bug, design

After looking around, I've been noticing some questions have larger text, and some have smaller text. For example, a question with large text.

[image]

Then here's a question with small text, almost unreadable for some people.

[image]

As you can probably tell, I'm using the full site on mobile Safari. Just to clarify, I'm neither zoomed out, or zoomed in, in either of these screenshots.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in Safari's text reflow algorithm than anything that has to do with Stack Exchange

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all either on my phone or on any desktop browser (chrome, IE, or Firefox) .

Comment: @AshleyNunn Must be some setting on my mobile safari tripping up the text.

Comment: Yeah, it is likely not a problem with Stack Exchange, but more an issue with your phone, like Private Pansy said.

Comment: I have seen this too on mobile Android, assuming it's a WebKit bug